# How to get key name of route using Router Class

Tags: php, laravel

I have one web route

```php
Route::post('users/{id}', [UserController::class, 'show'])->name('user.show');
```

Now, I need to get the `id` key using the `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route` class.

Is there any function that exists in the router that returns what we pass in the route binding?

Answer (score 0):

wherever in controller you can use the current request to do this:

```
$id=request()->route('id');
```

and thanks to  [Maksim's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11251946/maksim) comment below:
in the blade view file you can use the request() like:

```
 {{ request()->route('id') }}
```

Comment: I am not using from controller, I wan access from view

Comment: In view you can use request() helper like {{ request()->route('id') }}

Answer (score 0):

`Route::input('id')` would be the way to do it using the `Route` facade.